# json_decode, trying to access array element

Tags: php, mysql, json, object

```
$objetos = json_decode($_POST['objetos']);

$query1 = "DELETE FROM `usuarioObjeto` WHERE idusuario=" . $id . "";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysqli_error());



$size = count($objetos); //this  works
```

//this do not insert into the BD

```
for ($k = 0; $k < $size; $k++) {
    $ido = intval($objetos[$k]['id']);
    $cantidad = intval($objetos[$k]['cantidad']);
    $query2 = "INSERT INTO `usuarioObjeto`( `idUsuario`, `idObjeto`, `cantidad`) VALUES (" . $id . "," . $ido . "," . $cantidad . ")";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysqli_error());
}
```

thanks

and i have tried to access to one property like this but nothing

```
$ido = intval($objetos[0]['id']);
```

Comment: What is your `JSON` string?

Comment: `json_decode($_POST['objetos']);` replece to `json_decode($_POST['objetos'],true);`

Comment: that works ! thanks !!!!!

Comment: @Asier you can accept the answer.. so it can help to other people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_decode($_POST['objetos']);` replece to `json_decode($_POST['objetos'],true);`

By adding `true` as a second parameter, it will convert your `json` to `array`

More information: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
$objetos = json_decode($_POST['objetos'],true);
```